# How to rate objects programmatically in Django Star Rating

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using this library : [django-star-rating](https://github.com/wildfish/django-star-ratings) to rate model objects by scores given by users.
You can view the documentation [here](http://django-star-ratings.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Problem that I face:

1. How can I rate an object programmatically in view function rather than in the template.
2. Also how can I integrate it with Django Rest framework? It uses a generic relation in the model schema. So far, I have used the field as Serializer Method field but the problem with that is that it is read only and the client cannot make patch request to update rating.

Code so far:

```
from star_ratings.models import Rating

class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    rating = GenericRelation(Rating, related_query_name='example')



from rest_framework import serializers

class ExampleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    rating_total = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    rating_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_rating_total(self, obj):
        if obj.rating.exists():
            return obj.rating.first().total
        else:
            return 0

    def get_rating_count(self, obj):
        if obj.rating.exists():
            return obj.rating.first().count
        else:
            return 0
```

From drf [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) :

> SerializerMethodField
>
> This is a read-only field. It gets its value by calling a method on the 
>   serializer class it is attached to. It can be used to add any sort of data to the serialized representation of your object.

Hence the field is read only and I can't rate it from API client side.
I know Custom field exists for Generic relation but the documentation example is not thoroughly explained.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to go to source code of `django-star-rating` and understand how package works and then make it work accordingly. I'm not sure that you will get here any concrete solution since i will require to do the same thing as you should and that not what SO is used for.

Comment: I tried to understand the source code but it involves some components that I don't understand. I am still learning Django and so far, haven't been able to understand if the model parameters change via AJAX/ JavaScript event or by Django signal. Its proving very difficult to mimic the same in view due to lack of documented code.

Comment: I also opened a new issue regarding this in the repo before asking here. https://github.com/wildfish/django-star-ratings/issues/132

Comment: I believe until you don't understand the source code of libraries that you use you won't be able to rely on them and the way you use them.

Comment: Well, it's not just that, I also wanted to know how I can integrate the generic foreign key in drf HyperlinkedModelSerializer. Right now the field is Read Only. If I can make it writable, my problem will be solved. I have looked into similar questions and found that I need to define a custom field that can work with the generic relation but the documentation example does not help much.